# Available options for maintaining data consistency/sync across multiple systems

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, design-patterns

My question about what the best , tried and tested (and new?) methods  out there to do a fairly common requirement in most companies.
Every company has customers. And lets say a company A has about 10  different systems for its business needs.Customer is critical to all systems.
Customer can be maintained in any of the systems independently but if they fall out of sync then it’s not good. I know it’s ideal to keep one big master place/System for customer record and have all other systems take that information from that single location/system.
How do you build something like this.. SOA? ETLs? Webservice? Etc.. any other ideas out there that are new … and not to forget old methods. 
We are a MS / .NET shop. This is mostly for my knowledge and learning.. please point me in right direction and I want to be aware of all my options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally all your different systems would share the same database, in which case that database would be the master.  However that's almost never the case.

So the most common method I've seen is to have yet another system (lets call it a data warehouse) that takes feeds from your 10 different systems, aggregates them together, and forms a "master" view of a customer.

Comment: How about a single entry point. So I am thinking more in the lines of one system out of 10 being the "Master" system designate where all updates/new records get added. Then what options do I have to sync child system customer records with master all the time. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user - If you have a single entry point, then you could use a messaging system of some sort to send messages with updated information to each of the other systems.  The problem though is if people can additionally update data in those other systems without going through this "single entry point".  Also, how many of these 10 systems can you actually integrate with?  Are some proprietary purchased packages that are basicly a "black box" to you?

Comment: You are right. Currently what we are doing is not ideal, There are multiple entry points and they get out of sync soon. We need to do lot of manual script executions to clean up and sync. I am curious about the messaging system, can you please elaborate.

Comment: @user - What you have is a distributed messaging system (e.g. MSMQ) that you use to tell applications about changes that occurred in other applications.  So, for instance, if you update a customer in application X, have it send a message saying that the customer changed and what changed.  Applications Y & Z lets say can then subscribe to those messages and update its database accordingly.  This assumes of course that you have some way of "hooking into" all of these applications to make them send/subscribe to these messages.

Comment: A messaging system is a decent solution, it can be setup to work async, so one application could be offline and once started again could find the latest update messages.  Where WCF or such would require them being online at the time of the update, or would need a startup check method to be created additionally

Comment: Appreciate the insight both of you gave ... Thank you.

Comment: @EricPetroelje when you say "Hooking into".. all I need is access to the back end of those applications .. correct? I believe we have that for every system. Another question is.. I understand MSMQ messaging will act as a communication channel between master and other systems, but how is the actual data being updated? Just 'knowing' that there has been a change is different from actually getting synced.?

Comment: @user - easiest way would be to include the data that was updated in the message itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done anything like this, but playing with the idea here are my thoughts.  Perhaps something will be helpful.

This is a difficult question, and I'd say it mainly depends on what development ability and interfaces you have available in each of the 10 systems.  You may need a data warehouse manager piece of software working like my next paragraph says with various plugins for all the different types of interfaces in the 10 systems involved.

Thinking from the data warehouse idea: Ideally each Customer in each system would have a `LastModified` field, although that is probably unlikely.  So you'd almost need to serialize the Customer record from each source, store it in your data warehouse database with the last time the program updated that record.  This idea would allow you to know exactly what record is the newest any time anything changes in any of the 10 systems and update fields based on that.  This is about the best you could do if you're not developing some of the systems, only able to read from some fashion of an interface.

If you are developing all the systems, then I'd imagine WCF interfaces (I mention WCF because they have more connection options than webservices in general) to propagate updates to all the other systems (probably via a master hub application) might be the simplest option.  Passing in the new values and the date it was updated, either from an event on the save button, or checking a `LastModified` field every hour/day.

Another difficulty is what happens if one Customer object has an Address field and another does not, will the updates between those two overwrite each other in any cases?  Or if one had a `CustomerName` and another has `CustomerFirstname` and `CustomerLastname`

NoSQL ideas of variable data structure and ability to mark cached values as dirty also somewhat come to mind, not sure how much benefit those concepts would really add though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. NOSql is not an option because of the nature of business. Like the way you described one possible solution .. thank you.